# Persist chat messages in node

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, chat

I have built a chat app using node, express and socket io. But when I refresh the page, all the earlier chat messages are lost.

I did a little research and I read about REDIS but I am having difficulty on how to integrate redis. I searched for few node redis projects for the chat messages persistence but no luck.

Please suggest me a good approach on how to persist the chat messages and which technology is to use.

Any tutorial links are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Although its not necessary to use Redis for this kind of task.
From my point of view its a simple task, a limited size list.
Having that in mind you can approach this problem from different ways

- store in client database (browser database) the last N messages
- store in server the list and send to every new connection